# Java code for a net present value calculation

Tags: java, arrays, methods, encoding

Where I must write a code for a net present value calculation.

I need to use arrays! 
The discount rate is 10 % 
The cashflows for project 1 are: 500 , 300 , -200
for project 2 :                  -300 , 100 , 700.

So I don't know how I can get this running. Thanks for your help.

```
public class Netpresenvalue{

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        int [] [] cashflows = new int [] [] {{500, 300, -200}, {-300, 100, 700}};
        String [] projects = new String [] {"Project 1", "Project 2"};
        double [] netpv = npv (cashflows);
        report  (netpv, projects, cashflows);
    }

    public static double [] kapwert (int [] [] data) {
        double [] cap = new double [data[0].length];
        for (int i=0 ; i<data[0].length; i++) { 
            cap [i] = cashflows/Math.pow((data[0][i]));
        }
        return cap;
    }

    public static void report (double [] npv, String [] projects, int [][] cashflows) {
        for (int i=0 ; i<npv.length ; i++) {
            System.out.println("Project " + projects [i] + "has a npv of" + npv [i] + " and cashflows " + cashflows [1][i] + "Euro");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? "I don't know how I can get this running" isn't very specific. But I can see that you call a non-existing method in `main` and that you use a non-existing variable in `kapwert`. Does that help?

Comment: I am sorry. Kapwert should be named npv . However I don´t know how to integrate the discount rate in the code. Plus i don´t really know how to integrate the data (cashflows and discount rate) in the formula for the net present value.

Answer (score 0):

This is it, this will help you -

```
public class Netpresenvalue {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] cashflows = new int[][] { { 500, 300, -200 }, { -300, 100, 700 } };
        String[] projects = new String[] { "Project 1", "Project 2" };
        JusDoIt j1 = new JusDoIt(cashflows, projects);
        for (int i = 0; i < projects.length; i++) {
            double[] netpv = j1.npv(cashflows[i]);
            j1.report(netpv, projects, cashflows[i]);
        }
    }
}

class JusDoIt {
    int[][] cashflows;
    String[] projects;

    JusDoIt(int[][] cashflows, String[] projects) {
        this.cashflows = cashflows;
        this.projects = projects;
    }

    double[] npv(int[] data) {
    double[] cap = new double[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        cap[i] = data[i];
    }
    return cap;
}

    void report(double[] npv, String[] projects, int[] cashflows) {
        for (int i = 0; i < npv.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Project " + "has a npv of" + npv[i] + " and cashflows " + cashflows[i] + "Euro");

        }
    }
}
```

Now, the way you've written the code was horrible, your explanation wasn't clear, your basics are very bad, I can't expect it to be that bad and you said Thanks for your help, it showed like you haven't tried it properly, you haven't given all your efforts that's why your code was full of errors. We aren't here to do your homework, I hope you'll learn this from next time.